# Space of Lipschitz Functions

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity

The space of Lipschitz functions is a subspace of the space of continous functions. Why is it not closed under the same norm, and what exactly do they mean by this is the first place?

Comment: The closure of this space (say, on a segment) is the space $C$ of all continuous functions. Even piecewise linear functions or polynomials are dense in $C$.

Comment: Closed would mean that if a sequence of Lip functions converges uniformly, then the limit is Lip as well.Now take your favourite non-Lip. function and try to converge to it with Lip. functions to get a counterexample.

Answer (score 2):

Example: $x\mapsto \sqrt{x}$ is continuous $[0,1]\to \mathbb R$, but not Lipschitz. But you approximate it by the corresponding $n$-gons in the supremums norm; the Lipschitz constant of the $n$-gon goes to $\infty$ with $n$ on the first linear piece emanating from 0.